# Do governments publicly predict when global oil demand = oil supply?

Tags: commodities, crude-oil

My grandparents fancy buying an ETF of oil companies like FENY in the future. So they`re seeking reasonably evidenced predictions like [Rystad Energy's](https://www.rystadenergy.com/newsevents/news/press-releases/global-oil-glut-set-to-halve-in-may-and-shrink-to-just-6-million-bpd-in-june-but-storage-cant-breathe/):

[image]

Do governments predict like this too? If so, which?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, oil demand = oil supply at all times, if you consider storage demand as part of the demand.

In the very long term, oil demand and oil supply will decrease, because of the arrival of electric vehicles and hydrogen for long distance trucks.

If investing in energy companies, you should be investing in companies where the reserve depletion matches the annual reduction of oil demand. For example, I expect to own an electric car in the next 10 years. I suspect most car owners will likewise switch to electric vehicles. Why would I invest in a company that plans to produce oil for the next 20 years? In contrast, investing in a company that plans to produce oil for the next 10 years might be a good idea, as oil companies are not very highly valued now and oil will be needed still during the transition period to electric vehicles.

Whatever energy stocks you invest into, don't invest into coal! The reserves are very large, yet burning coal will be forbidden in lots of locations in a quite short timescale. So, most of the coal reserves end up being unutilized. Fortunately, most investors have realized this and coal companies have a valuation very close to zero. So, if buying a diversified fund of energy stocks, the weight of coal stocks is almost nonexistent.

You should also consider sector diversification, too. Going all in to oil stocks with all of your money is taking a huge risk.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://www.eia.gov/outlooks/steo/) a good starting point for you. The US government puts out supply/demand fundamentals via the EIA which is a part of the Dept. of Energy. You should note that in most cases data is lagged. However, it is one of the core datasets used by most private research companies.